# need help in getting this drop down menu to work

Tags: javascript, html

i followed instructions fromhttps://materializecss.com/dropdown.html ,still cant get this drop down to work.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.dropdown-trigger').dropdown();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js">
</script>
<!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">




<a href="#" class="waves-effect dropdown-trigger" id="dropdown" data-target="dropdown"><i class="material-icons">notifications</i></a>
<!-- Dropdown Structure -->
<ul id="dropdown" class="dropdown-content">
  <li><a href="#!">one</a></li>
  <li><a href="#!">two</a></li>
  <li class="divider" tabindex="-1"></li>
  <li><a href="#!">three</a></li>
  <li><a href="#!"><i class="material-icons">view_module</i>four</a></li>
  <li><a href="#!"><i class="material-icons">cloud</i>five</a></li>
</ul>

</li>
```

Comment: $ is not defined. You have no initialised jQuery by the looks of it.

Comment: added jquery still not working

Comment: Have you tried replacing ‘$’ with ‘jQuery’?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would you please check this? I found there was some wrong placement of some `li` items in your code. Also you didn't included the `jquery`. Otherwise all is working fine here.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.dropdown-trigger').dropdown();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js">
</script>
<!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">


<a class='dropdown-trigger waves-effect' href='#' data-target='dropdown1'><i class="material-icons">notifications</i></a>
  <!-- Dropdown Structure -->
  <ul id='dropdown1' class='dropdown-content'>
    <li><a href="#!">one</a></li>
    <li><a href="#!">two</a></li>
    <li class="divider" tabindex="-1"></li>
    <li><a href="#!">three</a></li>
    <li><a href="#!"><i class="material-icons">view_module</i>four</a></li>
    <li><a href="#!"><i class="material-icons">cloud</i>five</a></li>
  </ul>
```